# TCL - Call a proc with command line arguments not knowing the number of arguments to pass

Tags: command-line, arguments, tcl, command-prompt, proc

I will try to be clear.

I want to call a proc with some arguments from command line, but not knowing the number of arguments this proc needs.

I actually want to call in my tcl script a function from a dll. This function is just an interface to call some other functions, so the first argument to pass to this function is actually the function to finally use.

```
tcl myscript.tcl dll_final_function arg1 arg2 arg3
```

```
#DLL already loaded



#DLL function call

#It doesn't work but shows the "way" I want to do it
dll_interface $argv

#It works, but not in the "way" I want because I want a generic solution
dll_interface [lindex $argv 0] [lindex $argv 1] [lindex $argv 2] [lindex $argv 3]
```

Edit: dll_interface $argv or dll_interface {*}$argv returns an 'Invalid method' error from the dll function. It seems the dll function receive $argv as a whole string.

I can't change the way the dll works, and I hope I'm pretty clear with my description of the problem I have.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `dll_interface {*}$argv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all currently-supported versions of Tcl, you can use the expansion “operator” (it's not an operator in a technical sense, but you can pretend it is) to convert a list into multiple words, one for each list item. Since `argv` is a list already, your command becomes:

```
dll_interface {*}$argv
```

It is as simple as that.

---

In really old versions of Tcl you'd do this instead:

```
eval [linsert $argv 0 dll_interface]
```

but that's really non-obvious! (`eval dll_interface $argv` would work too, but has other more subtle problems that tend to crop up as you go to more complex situations.)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works. It seems I'm working with a old version of Tcl, eval [linsert $argv 0 dll_interface] was the right way to do in my case.